# Pandas dataframe only writing last row to .csv

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write these data frames to a `csv` file, however I am only writing the last row.  The objective of my code is to call an API and get the highest temperature for "yesterday" for a given lat/lng.

My current output is:

[image: Current Output]

I would like for my output to be:

[image: Desired Output]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame

#read csv

output_high_csv = r"C:\wab\outputempbeets1.csv"

se_ = requests.Session()

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata)
df = df [['lat', 'lon', 'field id']]

#convert Pandas series to string
dfText = df.astype(basestring)

#get lat/lng from dataframe
dfLat = dfText['lat']
dfLon = dfText['lon']
dfFid = dfText['field id']

#get values from series
latval = list(dfLat.values)
lonval = list(dfLon.values)
idVal = list(dfFid.values)
dayVal = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')

#Zip Field ID, Lat, Lng

for latrow, lonrow, idVal in zip(latval, lonval, idVal):
    #send lat/lngs to DTN
    url = 'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/daily-high-temperature/' + str(latrow )+'/' + str(lonrow) +'?start='+ dayVal +'T00:00:00Z&end=' +dayVal+'T01:00:00Z'+ '&unit=fahrenheit'
    r = se_.get(url, auth=('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'), timeout= 10)
    # print(r.url)
    hiTemp = (json.loads(r.content)['series'][0]['value'])
    strTemp = str(hiTemp)
    tempDF = {'field id': [idVal],
        'high temperature': [strTemp]
        }
    df = DataFrame(tempDF,columns= ['field id', 'high temperature'])    
    dfList = [df]
    dfs = [df.set_index('field id') for df in dfList]
    i = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
    print i
    i.to_csv(output_high_csv, encoding='utf-8', index=True)`
```

When I print `i` my output is:

[image: printed i]

EDIT: When I use `mode= 'a'`
Here is my output:

[When mode a is used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVNar.png)

Comment: You're iterating row-wise and calling `to_csv` which will ovewrite the csv on every iteration. After the first row, you need to pass `mode='a'` to append to the csv

Comment: Can you explain what your code is trying to achieve? Also, please use informative variable names, not `i` and `r`. Also `se_` is not defined, also it's pribably not relevant to the Q so maybe drop that logic from the question entirely. Lastly, how will `dfList` ever have more than one dataframe in it? Perhaps you want to define dfList outside the loop, append to it and then write to csv outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very convoluted. I think this is a simplified version of what you're attempting. It may have mistakes but if this doesn't answer your question, try and use it to simplify the code in your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
from pathlib import Path

DATA_PATH = Path('C:/wab')
input_csv = 'my_data.csv'
output_csv = 'outputempbeets1.csv'

se_ = requests.Session()

df = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH / input_csv,
                 usecols=['lat', 'lon', 'field id'],
                 dtype=str)

dayVal = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
dfs = []

def get_high_temp(lat, lon, dayVal):
    url = f'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/daily-high-temperature/{lat}/{lon}'
    params = {
        'start': f'{dayVal}T00:00:00Z',
        'end': f'{dayVal}T01:00:00Z',
        'unit': 'fahrenheit',
    }
    response = se_.get(url, 
                       params=params, 
                       auth=('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'),
                       timeout=10)

    hi_temp = str(json.loads(response.content)['series'][0]['value'])
    return hi_temp

for _, lat, lon, id_ in df.itertuples():
    hi_temp = get_high_temp(lat, lon, dayVal)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'high temperature': [hi_temp],},
                           index=[id_])    
    dfs = dfs.append(temp_df)

pd.concat(dfs).to_csv(DATA_PATH / output_csv, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with append mode:

```py
i.to_csv(output_high_csv, encoding='utf-8', index=True, mode='a')
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output. See original question.

Comment: That's because at each iteration you create a data frame where you can easily just add the values. Try to concatenate into a dataframe, get out of the loop and then write everything into a csv